# How to create custom exceptions in Java which show errors in lines?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I want to create a custom exception which displays lines, where error occurs.

I'm processing .txt files where structure looks like this :

[ONE]

DESCRIPTION= AA

A=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8]

B=[000 000  000 000]

C=  [1 2 3 4 5 1b a4 00]

---

And so on........

The problem is that sometimes in this file the closing bracket is missing when I'm processing it.

I've created new exception which looks like this

```
public class MalformedTxtFile extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 33436325235234;

    public MalformedTxtFile (){

    }

    public MalformedTxtFile(String message){
        super(message);
    }

    public MalformedTxtFile(Throwable cause){
        super(cause);
    }

    public MalformedTxtFile(String message, Throwable cause){
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

This file is really big, so I want to show the user in which line the problem happen.

How to extend MalformedTxtFile class to display those incomplete lines?

And how to create a good try catch block?

Comment: Why not just write the lines into the message of the Exception?

Comment: What you mean exactly?

Comment: `throw new MalformedTxtFile("Error in line 433: Dwarves are present")`

Comment: But this solution will break the whole process I want to process whole file and display lines, where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code, hope that works.

```
new MalformedTxtFile().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();
```

Comment: I believe the questions is about the file line number. Not the code.

Comment: Exactly, I need to display all the lines where something's missing